# How to use webworkers to highlight source code blocks using highlightjs?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-worker, highlightjs

How can i use one or more webworkers to highlight multiple small source code blocks on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example using one webworker**

To use only one webworker to highlight multiple code-blocks you might use the following code, where `highlight_code_worker_function` is the worker function.

```
<script>

    function highlight_code() {
        if (typeof (Worker) === undefined) return false;
        var workerFunction = new Blob(['(' + highlight_code_worker_function.toString() + ')()'], {type: "text/javascript"});
        var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(workerFunction));
        var codeBlocks = $('div.readme pre, div.readme code');
        worker.onmessage = function(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            codeBlocks.eq(data.index).html(data.result).addClass('hljs');
        };
        worker.onerror = function() {
            // do nothing
        };
        codeBlocks.each(function(index) {
            worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify({index: index, code: $(this).text()}));
        });
        worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify({index: -1}));
    }

    function highlight_code_worker_function() {
        onmessage = function(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (data.index === -1) {
                close(); // close worker
            }
            importScripts(''https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/highlight.min.js'');
            self.hljs.configure({tabReplace:4});
            var result = self.hljs.highlightAuto(data.code);
            postMessage(JSON.stringify({result: result.value, index: data.index}));
        }
    }

    highlight_code();

    </script>
```

**Example using multiple-web workers**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/styles/monokai_sublime.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function highlight_code()
      {
        if (typeof (Worker) === undefined) return false;
        var workerFunction = new Blob(['(' + highlight_code_worker_function.toString() + ')()'], {type: "text/javascript"});
        var localWorkerURL = URL.createObjectURL(workerFunction);
        $('div.readme pre, div.readme code').each(function() {
          var code = $(this);
          var worker = new Worker(localWorkerURL);
          worker.onmessage = function(event) { code.html(event.data).addClass('hljs'); }
          worker.postMessage(code.text()); // start worker
        });
      }

      function highlight_code_worker_function()
      {
        onmessage = function(event) {
          importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/highlight.min.js');
          self.hljs.configure({tabReplace:4});
          var result = self.hljs.highlightAuto(event.data);
          postMessage(result.value);
          close(); // close worker
        }
      }

      $(window).on('load', highlight_code);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is an old question but I am putting my answer that could help any future visitor.*

You can provide some delay between highlighting code snippets that will enhance the performance as all workers will not work simultaneously. I have personally used this approach in one of my websites and I get huge performance differences with it.

`script.js`

```js
const allPres = [...document.querySelectorAll('pre')];
for (let i = 0; i < allPres.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const block = allPres[i];
    var code = block.innerText,
    worker = new Worker('/worker.js');
 
    worker.onmessage = function (event) {
      var result = event.data;
      block.innerHTML = result;
      worker.terminate();
    };
 
    worker.postMessage(code);
  }, i * 500)  // putting just a delay of 500ms will make your website's performance nice than running all them together
}
```

`worker.js`

```js
importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.3.1/highlight.min.js');
 
self.onmessage = function (event) {
    var result = hljs.highlightAuto(event.data);
    postMessage(result.value);
};
```

*step by step implementation [here](https://stackblogger.com/highlight-code-using-web-workers/).*

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from the [official documentation](https://highlightjs.org/usage/), I came to a robust solution (I guess).

In fact, I created 3 scripts :

1. worker_functions.js
2. worker.js
3. script whithin HTML

Simply because I needed to highlight code dynamically. Here is my process :

1. Load the page with needed scripts, waiting for DOM loaded before running scripts.
2. Get some data from database, insert XML content in `data-my_attribute` within a button with `eye` icon.
3. Click those buttons will target the modal opening **(bootstrap 4)**.
4. **On modal show** (means **before** it is **shown**), get xml data from the button to put it in my code block.
5. **On modal shown** (means **when** it is **shown**), trigger the highlighting by sending message to the worker.

**EDIT**: The step 5 is not necessary, because `jQuery(this).find('#codeblock').html(xml);` is correctly done before starting the highlighting process.

---

### worker_functions.js

```
let highlight_worker;

/**
 * Start the worker in order to highlighting code block when triggering
 * @param worker_url - The javascript path of the worker
 */
function start_worker(worker_url) {
    highlight_worker = new Worker(worker_url);
}

/**
 * Start an highlighting process through the worker previously started
 * @param querySelector - The DOM element on which the highlighted content should be returned
 */
function start_highlighting(querySelector) {
    // Callback to insert the highlighted content to the expected element in DOM
    highlight_worker.onmessage = (event) => {
        querySelector.innerHTML = event.data;
    }
    
    // Post the content to be highlighted by the worker
    highlight_worker.postMessage(querySelector.textContent);
}
```

### Worker.js

I used a [custom package](https://highlightjs.org/download/) of highlight.js by including only languages I aim to highlight.

```
/**
 * When worker receives a message, import highlight.js then post back the resulting highlight
 * @param event - The content to be highlighted
 */
onmessage = function (event) {
    importScripts('highlight.pack.js');
    var result = self.hljs.highlightAuto(event.data);
    postMessage(result.value);
}
```

### Script within HTML - Django template

I import the `worker_functions` script, then I add an event listener triggering the window loading, start the worker, and trigerring the highlighting on modal events.

```
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{% static 'device/js/highlight/worker_functions.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
            start_worker("{% static 'device/js/highlight/worker.js' %}");
            $('#mifContentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                // let xml = '<p class="text-break">' + e.relatedTarget.dataset.mif_content + '</p>'; // Before decompress
                let xml = '<xmp>' + e.relatedTarget.dataset.mif_content + '</xmp>';
                console.log(jQuery(this).find('#codeblock'));
                jQuery(this).find('#codeblock').html(xml);
                start_highlighting(codeblock); // It can be done right after adding the code in DOM
            })
            //$('#mifContentModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            //    let codeblock = document.getElementById("codeblock");
            //    start_highlighting(codeblock);
            //    // Then remove the xmp tag
            //    codeblock.innerHTML = jQuery(this).find('xmp').html();
            //})
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Then I can highlight **whenever I want**, using a **single worker**.